# CSS with Image Div and Text Div for the same baseline

Tags: css, baseline

I'd like to place a Div for image and a Div for text at the same baseline.
Below is my sample code and JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/xLrf7pyt/

[image]

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="http://www.cssportal.com/images/cssportal.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="txt">
        This is text.
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .wrap { width: 500px;}
    .img { float: left; }
    .txt { }
</style>
```

============ Update ================

Originally, there should be some empty space between image (logo at left-top corner) and text (navigation at right-top) with same baseline with image logo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop the `float` from your `.img` element and instead set both `.img` and `.txt` to `display: inline`:

```css
.img, .txt { 
    display: inline;
}
```

Then set `.txt` to have a `vertical-align` of `baseline`:

```css
.txt {
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xLrf7pyt/3/).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment and it works. But, as I updated, I might have to use float to place image and text in the exact place. How to use float with your solution.

Comment: @Jay perhaps a better solution would be to set your `.wrap` element to `display: table` with a `width` of 100%, and your `.img` and `.txt` elements to `display: table-cell`. Then set your `.txt` element to have a `text-align` set to `right`.

Comment: @Jay: There's usually a (easier) way around positioning than floating elements.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I tested with your comment, but it present two rows. http://jsfiddle.net/xLrf7pyt/3/

Comment: @Jay that's the JSFiddle demo I linked in my answer.

Comment: @jutler483 if I use the position, I might have to set exact pixels.  The site will be responsive and I don't want to use conditions for this.

Comment: You have `display: text-cell` instead of `display: table-cell`. http://jsfiddle.net/xLrf7pyt/5/

Answer (score 0):

**Use** `display:inline;`

```css
    .wrap { width: 500px;}
    .img { display:inline; }
    .txt { display:inline; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="http://www.cssportal.com/images/cssportal.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="txt">
        This is text.
    </div>
</div>
```